# using onClick to get the id of the clicked button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Iam swaping the values of the button and the .innerHTML of the buttons as well, but doing it in a in-efficient way .
Like this :

```
function btnswap2()
{

    var soft=document.getElementById('1');
    var hard=document.getElementById('2');

    var temp;
    var temp1;
    var flag=0;

    if(soft.id==1)
        {
            temp1=soft.innerHTML;
            soft.innerHTML=hard.innerHTML;
            hard.innerHTML=temp1;

            temp=soft;
            soft=hard;
            hard=soft;

            showHARD();
        }
}
```

Now can i get the id of the button clicked in run-time, as you can see that the buttons get swapped every time i click the button.
Issue is i have to call some other function as here(in this case if it is hard then it should be hard else soft should be called)

```
  showHARD();
  showSOFT();
```

How can i achieve this ???
my butn id are as follows:
     BTN : ID

```
 SOFT: 1
 HARD: 2
 TRAI: 3
 STAT:4
```

Comment: Could you show us your HTML code?

Comment: I dont understand the condition `if(soft.id==1)` because if you get soft by his ID (`soft=document.getElementById('1')`) how can it be different from 1. Also like @naota said provide the HTML so we can better understand.

Comment: Moreover i have 4 buttons in total, out of which 1 is static(does nothing if clicked),and 3 buttons which onClick : will be swapped with the static button and its properties will change. Eg A(static) B,C,D(these buttons are live), after onClick(if i click on B) then B(static) A,C,D(live).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

**HTML**

```
--------
static:
--------
<div id="1" >button A</div>

--------
live:
--------
<div id="2" onClick="btnswap2(this.id)">button B</div>
<div id="3" onClick="btnswap2(this.id)">button C</div>
<div id="4" onClick="btnswap2(this.id)">button D</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function btnswap2(id){
    var temp = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML; // static button
    var clicked_label = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = clicked_label;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = temp;
}
```

Fiddle is here :http://jsfiddle.net/n5UDu/6/

Hope this helps.

Comment: can also suggest on how to get the value of the static button in real time... ur ans was correct that u gave thaks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to the static button:

```
<button id="1" >button1</button>
<button id="2" >button2</button>
<button id="3" >button3</button>
<button id="4" class="static" >button4</button>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){

  if($(this).hasClass("static")){
   showSTAT();
  }else{
   btnswap2(this); 
   if($(this).attr("id")=="1")
    showSOFT();
   else if($(this).attr("id")=="2")
    showHARD();
   else
    showTRAI();
  }
 });
});


function btnswap2(btn){

var stat=$('button.static');

var temp;

temp=btn.html();
btn.html(stat.html());
stat.html(temp1);

stat.removeClass("static");
btn.addClass("static");
}
```

Don't call showSOFT() or showHARD() in the btnswap2() function!

In this way you will get always the static button and it will swap only if the button swapped is not static.

Comment: I cannot do this as i have to swap the properties of the button that i have clicked and one static button. and then according to the id of the button swaped with i have to call the fuction showHARD()/showSOFT(); these function display properties of  the clicked button.

Comment: I changed my answer, see if it helps now